# Open a Popup using Image?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies, popup

I'm using WordPress on localhost and trying to add a popup or modal open using an image.
Tried using Popup Maker plugin-free version but it didn't work.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying another Plugin, "Popup anything on click" this is a one that I find in a single search!!